# Cakephp 2 Routing / SEO friendly urls

Tags: routes, cakephp-2.6

totally new to cakephp and really struggling to understand the docs.

Idea I'm working on is for a rental property search. I have controller rentalsController

In here I have index which I fetch all

I also have a sidebar which lists regions

Now, what I want to happen is for a user to view index and then go to sidebar and select a region they'd wish to rent from. The URL should be .com/rentals/region-name/

This will then call (could be wrong here) rentalsController > byRegion($region){ fetch.... )

How do I a) set-up routes to manage this and b) the function to gather that passed region.

Sorry if this basic but I've searched and now about to blow my mind - as you can imagine - we've all been here at one point learning a new way of doing things.

Thank you for all your feedback - Mark

EDIT

Finally got there:

```
Router::connect(
    '/rentals-in-:region.html', 
    array( 'controller' => 'rentals', 'action' => 'byRegion' ),
    array( 'region' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+', 'pass' => array('region'),
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If you are new to cake I wouldn't recommend to play around in your routes file. 
If you follow cake's conventions you could access your RentalsController::byRegion ($ region) action by calling /rentals/by_region/{region_name}.

Don't forget to create your view file app/View/Rentals/by_region.ctp

b)
Assuming your rentals table has a region field:

```
public function byRegion ($region){
    $this->set ('rentals', $this->Rental->find ('all', array (
        'conditions' => array (
            'Rental.region LIKE' => $ region
        )
    )));
```

**edit**:

Than you are looking for:

```
Router::connect(
   '/rentals/:region',
   array('action' => 'byRegion'),
   array('region' => '{your regex matching region}')
);
```

Add this to your routes file. You now should be able to call the url like you mentioned.
Should work but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Hi Ben - Thank you for your reply but it's not quite what I'm looking for - I'm looking for the same effect that we can produce with htaccess rewrite.

ie -  RewriteRule ^rentals-(.*).html$ rentals.php?region=$1 [l]

Comment: Thanks ben - you where close with your edit this is what I needed in the end

Router::connect(
 '/rentals-in-:region.html', 
 array( 'controller' => 'rentals', 'action' => 'byRegion' ),
 array( 'region' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+', 'pass' => array('region'),
));